# Base an if statement on the href of a clicked link

Tags: javascript, if-statement, href

I am new to stackoverflow and have a question regarding the following code:

JavaScript:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    "use strict";

    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#preloader').velocity({

            opacity: "0",

            complete: function() {
                $("#loading").velocity("fadeOut", {
                    duration: 1000,
                    easing: [0.7, 0, 0.3, 1],
                });
                $('body').addClass('loaded');   
                setTimeout(function() {
                   //Init waterpipe
                     var smokyBG = $('#canvas').waterpipe();
                }, 1000);
            }
        });
    }, 1000);
    setTimeout(function() {
        $(".link.left").css("left", "0px");
        $(".link.left1").css("left", "0px");
        $(".link.left2").css("left", "0px");
        $(".link.right").css("right", "0px");
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('.hero-text').each(function(i) {
                (function(object) {
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        $(object).addClass('fadeInDown').removeClass('opacity-0');
                    }, (i * 300) + 300);
                })(this);
            });
        }, 1200);
    }, 1000);


})


$(document).ready(function() {
    "use strict";

    /* ------------------------------------- */
    /* 2. Page Reveal Effect ............... */
    /* ------------------------------------- */
    var ifTouchDevices = navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPhone|iPod|iPad|Android|BlackBerry|Windows Phone)/);

    var revealerOpts = {
        nmbLayers: 3,
        bgcolor: ['#f5f5f5', '#33CCFF', '#323232'],
        effect: 'open-effect',
        onStart: function(direction) {
            if (direction === 'left') $("#about, #team").addClass('animate-' + direction); 
            else if (direction === 'right') $("#contact").addClass('animate-' + direction);


        },
        onEnd: function(direction) {
            $("#about").removeClass("animate-left");
            $("#team").removeClass("animate-left");
            $("#contact").removeClass("animate-right");
            if (isDesktop()) $(".service-header").addClass("opacity-0");
        }
    };
    var revealer = new Revealer(revealerOpts);

    function isDesktop() {
        if ($(window).width() >= 1000) return true;
        else return false;
    }

function reveal(direction) {
  var callbackTime = 750,
    callbackFn = function() {
      if (direction === 'left') {
        setTimeout(function() {
          $("#about").addClass("active");
          setTimeout(function() {
            $("#about").removeClass('in');
            setTimeout(function() {
              scrollbar('.about_content');
            }, 1000);
          }, 1200);
        }, 1000);
      } else if (direction === 'right') {
        setTimeout(function() {
          $("#contact").addClass("active");
          setTimeout(function() {
            $("#contact").removeClass('in');
            setTimeout(function() {
              scrollbar('.contact_content');
            }, 1000);
          }, 1200);
        }, 1000);

      }

revealer.reveal(direction, callbackTime, callbackFn);
    }

    /* ------------------------------------- */
    /* 3. Action Buttons ................... */
    /* ------------------------------------- */

    $('.link a').on( "click", function() {

        if (!isDesktop()) return;
        $("section.active").removeClass("active");
        $("#about").removeClass("active");
        $("#contact").removeClass("active");
        $("#team").removeClass("active");
        if (!$("#about").hasClass("in")) {
            $("#about").addClass("in");
        }
        if (!$("#contact").hasClass("in")) {
            $("#contact").addClass("in");
        }
        if (!$("#team").hasClass("in")) {
            $("#team").addClass("in");
        }

        var target = $(this).attr('href');
        reveal($(target).attr('data-direction'));
        return false;
    });
    /* Close Button */
    $('.btn-close').on( "click", function() {
        closeContent($(this).attr('href'));
        return false;
    });

    function closeContent(_target) {
        $(_target).addClass('out');
        setTimeout((function() {
            $(_target).removeClass('active out');
            $(_target).addClass('in');
            $('.hero-text').addClass('opacity-0');
            $('.hero-text').removeClass('fadeInDown');
            $("#body-container").addClass('active');
        }), 2200);
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('.hero-text').each(function(i) {
                (function(self) {
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        $(self).addClass('fadeInDown').removeClass('opacity-0');
                    }, (i * 300) + 300);
                })(this);
            });
        }, 3000);
    }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="link left">
  <div class="link-box"> <a class="link-box-left" href="#about" title="About Us">
      <p class="lmenu">ABOUT US</p>
    </a>
    <div class="lmenu-line-box">
      <div class="lmenu-line-mask">
        <div class="lmenu-line"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div> <a class="link-background left" href="#"></a> The section HTML: <section id="about" class="page-inner" data-direction="left">
```

On the website, the internal links are working with animations and the href does not become part of the url.

Until now, there were only two links on the page (left side and right side) but now I want to have several links on the left side, which is why I would like to change the if condition from "direction" to the href of the clicked link. Is there any way I can do that?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Can you also post the HTML?

Comment: Please take some time and take the [tour], read [ask], and how to create a [mre]. It will make your question-asking experience on Stack Overflow much better.

Comment: What happens with `callbackFn`? The code you posted is not complete (I won't judge about the quality).

Comment: The HTML of the link is as follows:

`<div class="link left">
  <div class="link-box">
   <a class="link-box-left" href="#about" title="About Us">
    <p class="lmenu">ABOUT US</p>
   </a>
   <div class="lmenu-line-box">
    <div class="lmenu-line-mask">
     <div class="lmenu-line"></div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <a class="link-background left" href="#"></a>`

The section HTML:

`<section id="about" class="page-inner" data-direction="left">`

Comment: @A1rPun Unfortunately I am not so sure what the callbackFn does... I didn't write the code.
I can give you the whole js code if you want, I just thought this was the important part.

Comment: No, sorry to say this but this code is not a good starting point to learn animations in HTML/JS.

Comment: I know. I can work with the rest of the code just fine, but I've been trying to get this if statement to work the way I want for two days now which is why I decided to ask for some help on here...

Comment: We need to see more of JavaScript code because otherwise a solution we would post would probably duplicate some of the existing code and cause even more of a headache for you.  However, the short of it is that on the click listener event you need to get the anchor element that was clicked and then you can access the href in your if statements easily: `anchorElement.href`.  For example, maybe you would pass it into the `reveal` function: `reveal(anchorElement.href)` and then in the reveal function just call it href: `function reveal(href){ ... }`

Comment: I really want to help you further but we are missing some context here. Which element is calling `reveal`. Where are the elements `.about_content` & `.contact_content`? The HTML doesn't seem to correlate with the JS you posted. I think you should go with a solution @j3py provided by passing the href to the function so you can check it with an `if` or `switch` statement.

Comment: Thanks to the both of you!
I have added the remaining JavaScript Code (up to the point where it has nothing to do with my question anymore) so it is easier to comprehend.

@J3py would your suggestion work with this code? Could you maybe give me precise directions now that you have the whole code? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: More code will not make it easier to comprehend but it will raise more questions IMHO. I do like you putting in the effort to make your question better. You are getting much faster and better help when posting a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we have all the context we need to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Following the OP's suggestion, let's try adding a new `data` attribute and argument to the `reveal` function.  We'll add the new `data` attribute to the HTML elements and modify both the `reveal` function as well as where the `reveal` function is called.  For example:

HTML:

```
    <div class="link left">
      <div class="link-box"> <a class="link-box-left" href="#about" title="About Us">
          <p class="lmenu">ABOUT US</p>
        </a>
        <div class="lmenu-line-box">
          <div class="lmenu-line-mask">
            <div class="lmenu-line"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div> <a class="link-background left" href="#"></a> The section HTML: <section id="about" class="page-inner" data-direction="left" data-subdir="about">

<div class="link left">
      <div class="link-box"> <a class="link-box-left" href="#other-about" title="Other About">
          <p class="lmenu">Other About</p>
        </a>
        <div class="lmenu-line-box">
          <div class="lmenu-line-mask">
            <div class="lmenu-line"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div> <a class="link-background left" href="#"></a> The section HTML: <section id="other-about" class="page-inner" data-direction="left" data-subdir="other-about">
```

JavaScript:

```
    function reveal(direction, subdir) {
      var callbackTime = 750,
        callbackFn = function() {
          if ((direction === 'left') && (subdir === 'about')) {
            setTimeout(function() {
              $("#about").addClass("active");
              setTimeout(function() {
                $("#about").removeClass('in');
                setTimeout(function() {
                  scrollbar('.about_content');
                }, 1000);
              }, 1200);
            }, 1000);
          } else if ((direction === 'left') && (subdir === 'other-about')) {
            setTimeout(function() {
              $("#other-about").addClass("active");
              setTimeout(function() {
                $("#other-about").removeClass('in');
                setTimeout(function() {
                  scrollbar('.other_about_content');
                }, 1000);
              }, 1200);
            }, 1000);
          } else if (direction === 'right') {
            setTimeout(function() {
              $("#contact").addClass("active");
              setTimeout(function() {
                $("#contact").removeClass('in');
                setTimeout(function() {
                  scrollbar('.contact_content');
                }, 1000);
              }, 1200);
            }, 1000);

          }  
...
...

   /* ------------------------------------- */
    /* 3. Action Buttons ................... */
    /* ------------------------------------- */

    $('.link a').on( "click", function() {

        if (!isDesktop()) return;
        $("section.active").removeClass("active");
        $("#about").removeClass("active");
        $("#contact").removeClass("active");
        $("#team").removeClass("active");
        if (!$("#about").hasClass("in")) {
            $("#about").addClass("in");
        }
        if (!$("#contact").hasClass("in")) {
            $("#contact").addClass("in");
        }
        if (!$("#team").hasClass("in")) {
            $("#team").addClass("in");
        }

        var target = $(this).attr('href');
        reveal($(target).attr('data-direction'), $(target).attr('data-subdir'));
        return false;
    });
```

Depending on the logic you need in the if statements above, you might want to do something different like this:

```
function reveal(direction, subdir) {
      var callbackTime = 750,
        callbackFn = function() {
          if (direction === 'left') {
            setTimeout(function() {
              $("#about").addClass("active");
              setTimeout(function() {
                $("#about").removeClass('in');
                setTimeout(function() {
                  scrollbar('.about_content');
                }, 1000);
              }, 1200);
            }, 1000);

            if (subdir === 'about') {
              // add your other logic here
            } else if (subdir === 'other-about') {
              // add your other logic here
            }

          } else if (direction === 'right') {
            setTimeout(function() {
              $("#contact").addClass("active");
              setTimeout(function() {
                $("#contact").removeClass('in');
                setTimeout(function() {
                  scrollbar('.contact_content');
                }, 1000);
              }, 1200);
            }, 1000);

          }  ...
```

Unfortunately, because I don't have a minimal working example it's impossible for me to make suggestions about how exactly to handle the internal logic there.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Unfortunately this somehow deactivates the whole animation and will also not show the content of the linked part of the website...

Comment: Did you make changes to the `reveal` function to handle the href instead of the direction in the if statements?

Comment: Do you mean like this:

`function reveal(href) {
        var callbackTime = 750,
            callbackFn = function() {`

When I do that Dreamweaver gives me errors in the following lines containing "direction". If I change them to "href" too, the animation will not play and nothing will be displayed.

Comment: Ah ok.  I'll update my answer with something else you can try.

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort!
I tried that before, unfortunately the animation doesn't recognize this (I had "left1") as a direction, so that the animation doesn't work. 

It does, however, display the correct content after a very awkward animation. It's pretty much the closest I have come to my desired outcome but due to the direction (only left, right, top, bottom are working) it looks very inconsistent...

Comment: For whatever reason it does show the correct animation (only on half the screen though) when I click on the "left1"-link after I have previously clicked the "left" or "right" link.

EDIT: It shows either the left or right moving animation, depending on which link I clicked just before.

Comment: Is it maybe possible to add another attribute to the sections in html that can be used with an `&&` in the if condition in JavaScript? What exactly would that have to look like in JavaScript?

Comment: Updated my answer with your suggestion.  Good luck!